# link between a given bone and it's fcurves?

Tags: python, animation, groups

I need to find the previous f-curve keyframe a particular pose bone, to test if any of the transform values have changed.  In fact my goal is iterating through all pose bones so I can keyframe_insert() new values where needed/changed, *and* possibly keyframe on a previous marker.

It's possible that some bone channel group names have been changed (e.g., instead of 7 location and rotation channels groups by bone name, there may be re-groupings like 'footIK.L.rotations' and 'footIK.L.locations', or some arbitrary re-grouping by a user like 'MyGroup'.  So I can't reliably get to the groups (previous keys) with the bone name, nor pose bone via the group name.

`bpy.data.objects['metarig.001'].pose.bones["footIK.R"]` may be in group `o.animation_data.action.groups['footIK.R.rot']`

in which case a reference like `o.animation_data.action.groups[ o.pose.bones['footIK.R'] ].channels[0]` would throw an exception.

Is there a way to the o.animation_data.action.group via the o.pose.bone or visa versa?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following (mess) seems to work, or would there be other problems?

`a_group.channels[0].data_path` gives a string value like:
`'pose.bones["thigh.R"].rotation_quaternion'`

```
for ag in o.animation_data.action.groups:
      pbName = ag.channels[0].data_path.split('"')[1] # bone name
      pb = o.pose.bones[ pbName ]
```

I was hoping for salvation, but I'll take a kludge.